# Move the variables pane in Pycharm's Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm

When debugging in PyCharm, I can move the `Variables` pane by dragging it, like so:
[image: debug side-by-side]
to
[image: debug vertical]

Using the latter layout (the vertical one) is very useful for me, especially in `Float/Window` view mode, as I'm debugging on a second screen which is rotated 90 degrees.

But when I'm using the Python Console for experimenting (e.g. running the code in `Scientific Mode`), I can't seem to find a way of moving the variables part from the horizontal (side by side) layout to a vertical one. The only thing I can do is resizing by dragging the separator between the console output and the variables.

[image: console side-by-side]

I'm aware of the possibility that the variables part of the Python Console is 'not the same type' as the `Variables` pane in the Debug window. But still, is there no way of moving the variables part below the console output? I'm using PyCharm Professional 2019.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: maybe post this as an issue with jetbrains?

Comment: It seems that there's already one, posted 4 months ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36575.

Comment: did you find any solutions for this issue ??